# Future space-based telescope array

Tags: astronomy, optics, telescopes

Radio-telescopes (e.g. the [Very Large Array (VLA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_Large_Array)) can simulate one gigantic dish by using separate smaller dishes.

**Q:** Could such an array of *optical* telescopes potentially see an exoplanet at say 20 LY away?

Assumptions:

- The array is space-based, at an ideal location such as the Earth-Sun
  L2 Lagrangian Point
- Assume the exoplanet of interest is defined as a rockey planet up to
  5 times the diameter of earth

Comment: I think that *"Can anyone speculate how [...]"* violates the FAQs ban on discussion. One might consider asking for a list of current proposals, but that would be Not Constructive (tm). I think that there are good, specific questions along these lines, but you will have to be more specific. Your (2), for instance is fine on it's own, and something like *"Are there any plans for a space based multi-antenna interferometer in the radio band (i.e. VLA in space)?"* would also be fine. I'm going to close for the moment, but please edit and flag to get it re-opened. There is a good question in here.

Comment: Question 2 quite relies on question 1. In fact I don't see why there needs to be 2 questions, just ask the second.

Comment: @Lakey, radio telescopes use a very different way of collecting and combining their data than we would with an optical telescope. It relies on catching the same photon/wavefront in multiple detectors so we can combine them together. Optically, things work very differently. Take a look at Optical Interferometry if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure...why not?  The answer is really in the diffraction limit.

Two NASA missions planned to address this based upon sparse apertures:  SIM and TPF.  SIM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Interferometry_Mission) was a variable distance pair of telescopes.  TPF (http://exep.jpl.nasa.gov/TPF-I/tpf-I_index.cfm) was a synchronized flying mission of several telescopes phased together.

Concepts today are based upon Fourier Telescopy (several apertures phased together sort of like an interferometer or a star nulling telescope).  The Navy does something similar on the ground (see: NPOI http://www.lowell.edu/research_telescopes_npoi.php).  JPL / Caltech have done something similar on the ground at Palomar Observatory (http://www.astro.caltech.edu/palomar/pti.html)